# Reverse and Forward DNS set up correctly but sometimes MapReduce job fails

Tags: hadoop

Ever since we switched over our cluster to communicate via private interfaces and created a DNS server with correct forward and reverse lookup zones, we get this message before the M/R job runs:

`ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase - Cannot resolve the host name for /192.168.3.9 because of javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]; remaining name '9.3.168.192.in-addr.arpa'`

A dig and nslookup both show that the reverse and forward look-ups both get good responses with no errors from within the cluster.

Shortly after these messages, the job runs...but every once in awhile we get a NPE:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
INFO  app.insights.search.SearchIndexUpdater -  at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.reverseDns(DNS.java:93)
INFO  app.insights.search.SearchIndexUpdater -  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.reverseDNS(TableInputFormatBase.java:219)
INFO  app.insights.search.SearchIndexUpdater -  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:184)
INFO  app.insights.search.SearchIndexUpdater -  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1063)
INFO  app.insights.search.SearchIndexUpdater -  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1080)
INFO  app.insights.search.SearchIndexUpdater -  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
INFO  app.insights.search.SearchIndexUpdater -  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:992)
INFO  app.insights.search.SearchIndexUpdater -  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:945)
INFO  app.insights.search.SearchIndexUpdater -  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
INFO  app.insights.search.SearchIndexUpdater -  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
INFO  app.insights.search.SearchIndexUpdater -  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
INFO  app.insights.search.SearchIndexUpdater -  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:945)
INFO  app.insights.search.SearchIndexUpdater -  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:566)
INFO  app.insights.search.SearchIndexUpdater -  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:596)
INFO  app.insights.search.SearchIndexUpdater -  at app.insights.search.correlator.comments.CommentCorrelator.main(CommentCorrelator.java:72`

Does anyone else who has set-up a CDH Hadoop cluster on a private network w/DNS server get this?

CDH 4.3.1 with MR1 2.0.0 and HBase 0.94.6

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your internal DNS servers are not responding quickly enough to the number of requests that can come in from your Hadoop environment (depending on it's size).

You can do one of several things:

1. Set up a caching-only nameserver that only handles requests for your Hadoop cluster.  You will need to configure this name server before any other nameserver in each host's /etc/resolv.conf.
2. Enable nscd to do short-lived hostname lookup caching on each server running in your hadoop cluster.
3. Edit /etc/hosts on each server in your Hadoop cluster to contain a complete list of every IP/Hostname pair for each server in your cluster.

Setting up a caching-only nameserver is pretty trivial.  You should be able to find a tutorial appropriate for doing it appropriate to your OS with a little searching.

Setting up nscd is also pretty trivial, with the caveat that it can sometimes cause wonky things to occur (such as host name changes taking longer than you expect).  If a sufficiently short enough cache time, this hasn't been an issue for us.  I would recommend disabling the passwd and group caching that nscd can enable.  The cache time doesn't need to be very long.  600 seconds seems like a good balance for our cluster and reduces the actual DNS lookups pretty significantly.  Even 60 seconds would be better than hitting the DNS server repeatedly.

My config file looks like this:

```
    logfile         /var/log/nscd.log
    threads         6
    max-threads     128
    server-user     nscd
#   stat-user       nocpulse
    debug-level     0
#   reload-count        5
    paranoia        no
#   restart-interval    3600

    enable-cache        passwd      no
    positive-time-to-live   passwd      600
    negative-time-to-live   passwd      20
    suggested-size      passwd      211
    check-files     passwd      yes
    persistent      passwd      yes
    shared          passwd      yes
    max-db-size     passwd      33554432
    auto-propagate      passwd      yes

    enable-cache        group       no
    positive-time-to-live   group       3600
    negative-time-to-live   group       60
    suggested-size      group       211
    check-files     group       yes
    persistent      group       yes
    shared          group       yes
    max-db-size     group       33554432
    auto-propagate      group       yes

    enable-cache        hosts       yes
    positive-time-to-live   hosts       600
    negative-time-to-live   hosts       20
    suggested-size      hosts       211
    check-files     hosts       yes
    persistent      hosts       yes
    shared          hosts       yes
    max-db-size     hosts       33554432
```

Finally, going the /etc/hosts route:  I would not recommend this if you have a large cluster.  It's just too administratively expensive to make sure all your configurations are up to date.